# Do messages drop in zeromq pull/push when client disconnects

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

I am using ZMQ to allow multiple clients to connect to a server and send a video stream of data using Pull/Push pattern. Now issue is the client can disconnect from the server. I need to ask is there a reliability concern, what happens if the data being sent to the server is dropped. Will the client will start sending video streams from the start or from where it was dropped in ZeroMQ. Does using Pull/Push pattern has buffers to accommodate this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually ZeroMQ sockets will automatically reconnect when a connection is lost due to a temporarily network error.

For a PUSH socket the [documentation](https://zeromq.org/socket-api/#pipeline-pattern) states:

> When a PUSH socket enters the mute state due to having reached the high water mark for all downstream nodes, or if there are no downstream nodes at all, then any send operations on the socket will block until the mute state ends or at least one downstream node becomes available for sending; messages are not discarded.

So a PUSH socket will buffer data and eventually block if it is not connected to a downstream PULL socket.

You should be able to test this by temporarily disabling or unplugging the network.

Comment: thank you very much your comment is really helpful.